# How can I use MAX or last in ASP using SQL

Tags: sql, asp-classic

I have the follwing code in my form query

```
<%  
divrec = request.QueryString("div")
Set rstest = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rstest.locktype = adLockOptimistic
sql = "SELECT MAX (Division_Program) AS 'Division 1' FROM CensusFacility_Records "
rstest.Open sql, db
%>
```

But I get the following error

> ADODB.Recordset
>   error '800a0cc1'
>   Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal.

Comment: What's the database type? You should ensure that `Division_Program` column exists in table `CensusFacility_Records`. Could be a typo. If the column exists, please provide the connection string of `db`.

Comment: Also, depending on the db type, it may be a case-sensitivity problem. All things being equal, I treat everything like it is case-sensitive. That way I'm either right or pleasantly surprised.

Comment: @AnonJr good point! In some setups table and column names may have case-sensitivity. I've had such a problem with Turkish-Regional install.

Comment: I think you need to lose the space after  MAX (ie "MAX(Division_Program)" rather than "MAX (Division_Program)".  That query as it is will look for a column called MAX.

Comment: How are you you accessing the recordset value later on ? `rstest("division 1")` ?

Comment: @Kul-Tigin I'm using SQL SQL Server and the colum exist.

Comment: @Jimmy Ok then. As `@SearchAndResQ` asked, how are you you accessing the recordset value? It's the problem.